Right format of the element path
I'd like to know what is the right (official) way to use element path in Robot Framework.
According to the doc:

Let's say I want to use xpath. If I understand the right way to use it in a KW for example:
Wait Until Page Contains Element    locator=xpath://*[@id="post-message-container"]

But in many cases, googling it, I found this:
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//*[@id="post-message-container"]

Surprisingly both work, but I don't think the second one should.
Could you help me to solve this confusion?

I guess you are referring to the SeleniumLibrary. According to the documentation - The explicit locator strategy is specified with a prefix using either syntax strategy:value or strategy=value. The former syntax is preferred because the latter is identical to Robot Framework's named argument syntax and that can cause problems. So I guess the best practice is to use xpath://div method?

@Pramesh can you show me the "strategy=value" case in the documentation? I can not see it, only the "strategy:value" i can find. I'd like to ask you why did you answer in the comment instead of the "Answer"? In this case it is not possible to "Accept" your answer

There is no strategy=value examples in the official documentation because their recommended syntax is strategy:value. However, if you look at another similar library called Browser library , you will find that they have used syntax strategy=value. I guess it just depends on the library and their recommendations.

Python allows method/function arguments to be passed in out-of-order when you mention the name of the argument. For example:
def foo(x, y):
  print(f"x: {x}")
  print(f"y: {y}")

foo(1,2)
foo(y=1,x=2)

This is most likely due to how kwargs in python is implemented. Since robot itself runs on top of python, it honours this convention.
Most typical place to use this convention is when there are kwargs used but in this particular case, the locator is just normal positional argument as that keyword looks like this:
    @keyword
    def wait_until_page_contains_element(
        self,
        locator: Union[WebElement, None, str],
        timeout: Optional[timedelta] = None,
        error: Optional[str] = None,
        limit: Optional[int] = None,
    ):

In this case, only timeout, error and limit are optionals (eg, they have a default value  if the value is not passed in).
So, passing in argument to a keyword in format that mentions its variable name most likely serves a purpose documentation of sorts. Defining that the first argument should be the locator is stating that explicitly vs when its omitted, its only implicit and relies on the fact that caller knows the order of the arguments.
